# python multiprocessing not processing task

Tags: python

In a wx GUI I need to call a method that will run for a while, and in my research the only bit of code I vaguely understand was a multi processing example [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935515/wxpython-non-blocking-gui-threading-and-multiprocessing) I've tried to adapt this code to my needs, here is the relevant section of my code:

```
            def OnStart(self, event):
                images = self.getImageList()
                jobs = mp.cpu_count() * 2
                for job in range(jobs):
                    mp.Process(target = myWorker, args = (images)).start()

    (external to tv class, displayImage is a @staticmethod)        
    def myWorker(images):
        print "yo"
        for image in images:
            tv.displayImage(image)
```

My issue is that is never executes the code in myWorker, nor does it give me errors.

Answer (score 0):

The argument sent to the `args` parameter should be a sequence. It should have the same length as the number of arguments that `myWorker` expects. Since `myWorker` expects one argument, `args` should be a sequence of length one. So try:

```
mp.Process(target = myWorker, args = (images,)).start()
```

Note the comma after `images`, which makes `(images,)` a tuple.

Though not directly an answer to your question, you may also find this page, on [how to deal with Long Running Tasks](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks) useful.

Comment: i tried that, still doesnt do anything. i also tried giving args a generator instead of a list, but I got a pickling error. That site just conufuses me, its the reason I thought maybe mp would be better than threads.